# Arduino convert a DEC to an int

Tags: type-conversion, arduino

I have the [DHT11 temperature](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/DHT11Lib) sensor and I am trying convert the humidity into a number I can use in compare statments.

If I use:

```
Serial.print("Humidity (%): ");
Serial.println((int)DHT11.humidity, DEC);
//Prints: 38 for the humidity
```

However if I use

```
  int tempHum;
  tempHum = ((int)DHT11.humidity, DEC);
  Serial.print("Humidity (%): ");
  Serial.println(tempHum);
  //Always Prints: 10
```

How can I make the humidity into an accurate number other than the serial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time you're posting, please add a link to the library you're using - that way we're sure to talk about the same. You haven't posted all of your code, but looking at [this](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/DHT11Lib), it seems to me, that this line `tempHum = ((int)DHT11.humidity, DEC);` is cause your problems.

If you try to use `tempHum = DHT11.humidity` instead, you might have better results. This is because the cast you're doing and adding the `DEC` parameter seems to be to the println function, so that the underlying system knows which type it should print.

Of course you all need to remember to do a `int retval = DHT11.read(DHT11PIN)` and check on your retval that nothing went wrong - this should make it work.